# Better anti-aliasing on iPad when using position: fixed, why?

Tags: html, css, ipad, fonts, antialiasing

I noticed that when using `position: fixed` on an element, the text on the iPad (iOS 5.0.1)  is being rendered better than without `position: fixed`. This is especially the case for white text on darker background.

My question is how to make use of this improved anti-aliasing without using workarounds such as `position: fixed`.

Below you can find an example picture and the corresponding code.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/t4kTm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to iOS 5 I wasn't able to reproduce this anymore - weird.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why that is, but I do know how to control anti aliasing in webkit browsers:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: none; /* Obvious */
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; /* This is what quite a few browers already do*/
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* Even more than the one above */
```

Will this help?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, unfortunately this wasn't it

Comment: That's fine. Does it make a difference at all, because I'm sure iOS uses WebKit?

Comment: the latter two don't make a difference (I guess because subpixel-antialiasing is OS dependent). Turning it off completely (none) does, and it looks horrible. ;)

Comment: iOS can't do subpixel antialiasing since the orientation of the screen can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad, applying `position:fixed` to the body tag makes the font thinner for all child elements (appearance similar to `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`). I haven't tested exhaustively, but it works with Helvetica Neue in iOS 5.1.1

```
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  // make fonts thinner in desktop Webkit
  position: fixed;                      // make fonts thinner on the iPad
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. I find the font rendering in iOS to be strange anyway...